# Display charts based on checkbox selection - highcharts

Tags: javascript, checkbox, highcharts

I have three charts, right now, all three charts are displayed by default.
I want them to be displayed based on check boxes I click.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input').forEach(function(checkbox) {
checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
const id = e.target.dataset.id,
  checked = e.target.checked,
  checkedCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes input:checked').length,
})
})
```

Please find the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uL3qz5tm/

First chart should be displayed by default (on load).
If chart1 and chart2 are checked, chartOne and ChartTwo graphs must be displayed.
If all three checkboxes are checked, all three graphs must be displayed.
If all three checkboxes are unchecked, page must be empty.

I have commented out code I had tried (under -> Display chart based on checkbox selection), they are not efficient or behaves exactly how I want.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can change style on hidden/visible when switching checkbox.

```
let chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container1', {

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  }],

});

let chart2 = Highcharts.chart('container2', {

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].reverse()
  }],

});

let checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
let container1 = document.getElementById('container1');

checkbox1.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (container1.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    container1.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    container1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
})

container2.style.visibility = 'hidden';

checkbox2.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (container2.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    container2.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    container2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
})
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ju2Ld7c1/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found it useful. But I wanted to know if charts can be displayed based on checkbox selection in 'synchronized charts' as shown in my fiddle.

Comment: In this proposal you can introduce chart sync, what exactly do you want to achieve and why do you need a different solution?